# Move rows to another sheet when row is added, then delete

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Needing to move a row from a source sheet to destination sheet when a row is added to source sheet.
Then delete the source sheet row.

This is what I have but I keep getting errors:

```
 function moveValuesOnly () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Source");
  var source = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Destination");
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
  source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  source.clear ();
}
```

Comment: How is the row added to the source spreadsheet? Is it due to a user edit?

Comment: Please provide the exact error messages you are receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try your function this way:

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  let lr = sh.getLastRow();
  var rg = sh.getRange(lr,1,1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var drg = dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  rg.copyTo(drg, { contentsOnly: true });
  sh.deleteRow(lr);
}
```

But this function will not be called by an onChange event of type "INSERT_ROW" unless the insert row is a user edit.

So for example:

If you create an installable onMyChange trigger of type onChange then the function insert row will not initiate moveValuesOnly because the onChange event is only triggered when a user inserts a row not when a formula or a script inserts the row.

```
function onMyChange(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  if(e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW") {
    moveValuesOnly();
  }
}

function insertRow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  sh.insertRowAfter(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first example works well. How can I move all the rows, except for the header row, to Sheet1 when a row or rows are added? Also, should I use the second example combined with the first to insert a new row or rows to Sheet1? I anticipate there could be multiple entry rows the Sheet0 and they will all need to be moved...Sorry for the confusion

Comment: You have not answered the question regarding how the row will be inserted.  I gather that you did not actually read my answer because I said `the function insert row will not initiate moveValuesOnly because the onChange event is only triggered when a user inserts a row` so again I still do really know how you are planning to insert rows.  If you are not inserted by users the the move function will not work

Comment: What is sheet0 update?

Comment: The row is added automatically when a user submits a form(completes an action)

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand your answer. When a user performs an action, the source sheet will automatically add a row. Then it should follow the script to move the row to the destination sheet. Delete from source

Comment: So from your comment `The row is added automatically when a user submits a form(completes an action) ` I gather that the sheet is a linked sheet to a google form in that case a row is added but I'm not sure in it will trigger another onChange event I'll have to check.

Comment: When a user insert or deletes a row then onChange will fire if user edits a cell onchange will fire and there are other situation.  I guess the point is that if you are having trouble with an onChange or an onEdit you should set up the trigger the capture the event object and then setup what you hope will generate the trigger and if it doesn't then it won't work.   And keep in mind there is considerably less information in the onChange event object and the onEdit event object.

Comment: OK. Thanks alot